# How select a closest element (must not be a parent of this) using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, parent, closest, dom-traversal, jquery-traversing

Assume an html document:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <li id="eee">
      <li>aaa</li>
      <span>bbb</span>
        ...
          <div>
            <button id="ccc">ddd</button>
          </div>
        ...
    </li>
  </body>
</html>
```

Using `$('#ccc').closest('li')` jQuery will select the `<li id="eee">...</li>` - the nearest ancestor of the `<button id="ccc">`. Is it possible to select `<li>aaa</li>` as "really" closest `<li>` element to the `<button id="ccc">` (so, it need not be an ancestor, but enough be a **sibling of one of the ancestors**)?

### Update:

valid html (specially for @PSL guy, already deleted his comments):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="eee">
      <div>aaa</div>
      <span>bbb</span>
      <ul>
        <li>fff</li>
        <li>
          <button id="ccc">ddd</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </body>
</html>
```

how to get the `<div>aaa</div>` without using the `parent()` function, but using smth. like `trueClosest('div')` taking siblings, ancestors and siblings of the ancestors in account?

I just want to know, if jQuery has such a function or not?

Comment: ok, it is invalid, but chrome still can perform on it, so it is possible to understand what I mean. The question is conceptual: is it possible to select not the direct nearest ancestor (father, (grand)father) but a sibling of any ancestor (uncle, brother of (grand)father), that match an expression (e.g. `closest(expression)`)

Comment: specially for @PSL a VALID html in update of the question, if it is not clear form the original, what and how I want to select and what and how I don't want.

Answer (score 7):

One could use the following:

```
$('#startingElement').closest(':has(#desiredElement)').children('#desiredElement')
```

So: find the closest element to the `#startingElement` which has a `#desiredElement` and then get it(them) through `children(function);`

Answer (score 0):

**Does this help?**
I often use this method when traversing the DOM for parents/siblings

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('#something')
```

Comment: but unfortunately I don't know, how deep is the `#something` from `this`